# How to use Dbmapper to generate JPA entity classes from DB script?

Tags: java

I am tring to use http://code.google.com/p/dbmapper/ and I am not sure how to run it frmo the command prompt.

The sample usesege is like below

```
Usage: com.moonspider.dbmap.GenerateConfig
  -type (-t) [String] The type to generate, either 'jpa' or 'gorm' (experimental) (jpa)
  -destinationDirectory (-d) [String] Destination directory
  -url [String] The url of the database
  -pkg (-package) [String] The target package ()
  -user (-u) [String] Database user (sa)
  -password (-p) [String] Database password ()
  -globalExtends (-extends) [String] Class for all Java classes to extend
  -globalImplements (-implements) [String] Class for all Java classes to implement
  -driver [String] Database drive class
  -extension (-ext) [String] File extension for the generated code (java)
  -hibernate [String] Generate hibernate.cfg.xml to this directory
  -jaxb [flag] Enable xml binding generation
  -schema [String] Specify the non-default schema to use
```

How to run `com.moonspider.dbmap.GenerateConfig`
 from command line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example to run with a MySQL database, run it as:

```
java -cp /path/to/lib/mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar:dbmap-r12.jar \
com.moonspider.dbmap.Generator -t jpa -d entities -url jdbc:mysql://localhost/jpagen \
-pkg com.xyz.data.entity -u user -p pass -driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```